# Trouble with imports in IntelliJ IDEA CE for and FTC Robotics Simulator

Tags: intellij-idea, import, compiler-errors, robotics

I am trying to use the virtual robot simulator designed by team Beta#8397 and got the simulator working. Now I am trying to put my teams code in so that we can test it. I am getting a bunch of errors that I'm pretty sure all stem from one error that some of the imports aren't importing. Also, my teams code builds fine when not combined with the simulator. I'm not amazing a java, but do know how most of my teams code works. Here is the code for the imports

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.Robovines;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Disabled;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.robot.Robot;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.Hardware;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.Range;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Disabled;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Autonomous;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DigitalChannel;
```

The errors are on lines 4,5 and 13 with the package being the first line. On line 4 the error is that `com.qualcomm.robotcore.robot.Robot` does not exist. On lines 5 and 13 the error is that symbol "Hardware" and "DigitalChannel" respectively cannot be found.
[Here is the whole project](http://www.filedropper.com/virtualrobot-mastercopy)

Comment: Make sure the required jars are added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don’t know what you mean

Comment: Where are the imports that are missing located in your project? If you don't understand how it works and want to get help, the best way would be to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the others so that we can download your project and see what is the problem with the configuration/dependencies, etc.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I added the whole file

Comment: Sources for these files are not present in the `Controller` module. You either need to implement them yourself or get a different version of this module that has these classes: com.qualcomm.robotcore.robot.Robot
com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.Hardware
com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DigitalChannel .

Comment: For example `com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DigitalChannel` is available here: https://github.com/ftctechnh/ftc_app/blob/master/libs/RobotCore-release-sources.jar.

Comment: I have no idea if that worked. I just put the file in the hardware section under controller. Now I'm getting this error Error:(4, 47) java: package com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode does not exist

Comment: If I was going to implement them myself, how would I do that

Answer (score 0):

@BookNinja S : The link you provided doesn't take me to your code.

The virtual robot simulator provides a subset of the functionality of the FTC SDK.

That subset has increased over time, but as commented by @CrazyCoder, the Controller module does not include the com.qualcomm.robotcore.robot.Robot, com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.Hardware, or com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DigitalChannel classes.

With regard to DigitalChannel, this type of sensor is not part of the virtual robot functionality. But, it would be easy to add a dummy DigitalChannel class to the controller (so, getState would always return false, and setState would do nothing).

Dummy classes could probably be used for Hardware and Robot as well, but that would depend upon how you are using those classes in your op modes.

If you submit this as an issue on the virtual_robot github repository, with a link to your project or an explanation of how you are using the Hardware and Robot classes, we (ftc team Beta 8397) can probably add the needed functionality to the virtual_robot project.